# Drupal removing a node reference from a node

Tags: drupal-6, cck

Ok, trying to process a script, both PHP and JavaScript, where I am moving a particular content type NODE from one reference to another.  This is the structure:

I have a PROJECT
Inside each PROJECT are PAGES
Inside each PAGE are CALLOUTS
and Inside each CALLOUT are PRODUCTS.

What I want to do is take a PRODUCT from one CALLOUT to another CALLOUT.  I am able to merge these, but now what I want to do is delete the first instance.  An example:

I have PRODUCT `AAG-794200` that is on PAGE 6 CALLOUT A.  I am merging that PRODUCT with PAGE 6 CALLOUT B.

I can get the product to merge, but now I need to remove it from CALLOUT A.  Here is my code:

```
$merge = explode(',', $merge); //Merge SKUs
$mpages = explode(',', $mpages); //Merge Pages
$mcallouts = explode(',', $mcallouts); //Merge Callouts
$mcallout_nid = explode(',', $mcallout_nid);  //Merge Current callout

$length = count($merge);
$e = 0;
while ($e < $length) {
    //Where is the SKU going to?
    $to_callout_letter = strtoupper($mcallouts[$e]);
    $to_page_num = $mpages[$e];
    $sku = $merge[$e];
    $from_callout = $mcallout_nid[$e];

    //Where is the SKU coming from?     
    $other_callout = node_load($from_callout);

    //Need page ID of current callout for project purposes
    $page_nid = $other_callout->field_page[0]['nid'];
    $page = node_load($page_nid);
    //Need the project NID
    $project_nid = $page->field_project[0]['nid'];

    //We need to get the NID of the page we are going to
    $page_nid = db_query('SELECT * FROM content_type_page WHERE field_page_order_value = "%d" and field_project_nid = "%d" ORDER BY vid DESC LIMIT 1', $to_page_num, $project_nid);

    $page_nid_res = db_fetch_array($page_nid);
    $to_page_nid = $page_nid_res['nid'];

    //We need to get the NID of the callout here
    $co_nid = db_query('SELECT * FROM content_type_callout WHERE field_identifier_value = "%s" and field_page_nid = "%d"', $to_callout_letter, $to_page_nid);
    $co_nid_res = db_fetch_array($co_nid);
    $to_callout_letter_nid = $co_nid_res['nid'];


    //Load the present callout the SKU resides on
    $f_callout = node_load($from_callout);

    $callout = node_load($to_callout_letter_nid);
    $long = count($f_callout->field_skus);
    $deletecallout = array();
    foreach($f_callout->field_skus as $skus) {
        $s = 0;
        while ($s < $long) {
            if($skus['nid'] == $sku) {
                $callout->field_skus[] = $skus;
                $s++;
            }
            else {
                $deletecallout[] = $skus;
                $s++;
            }
        }
    }


    foreach($other_callout->field_images as $old_image) {
        $callout->field_images[] = $old_image;
    }
    foreach($other_callout->field_line_art as $old_image) {
        $callout->field_line_art[] = $old_image;
    }
    foreach($other_callout->field_swatches as $old_image) {
        $callout->field_swatches[] = $old_image;
    }

    $callout->field_copy_text[0]['value'] .= $other_callout->field_copy_text[0]['value'];
    $callout->field_notes[0]['value'] .= $other_callout->field_notes[0]['value'];
    $callout->field_image_notes[0]['value'] .= $other_callout->field_image_notes[0]['value'];
    $callout->field_status[0]['value'] = 'In Process';
    node_save($callout);
```

This causes the PRODUCTS to MERGE, but not delete the original.

Thanks for any help.  I know it's something simple, and it will be a palm-to-face moment.

Comment: Your code snippet is not long enough to understand what is going on. There are variables there that have no explanation whatsoever. Please provide more information.

Comment: @kekkis - Full function is posted.

Comment: It looks like you're populating a $deletecallout array in the foreach loop, but then not doing anything with it.  Is that what's missing?  And your code is still incomplete.  Where is the ending brace of the while($e < $length) loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to solve this myself.  @Chris - The brace ended after `node_save(callout);`  I must have missed that when I copied and pasted.  However, here is the code I ended up using:

```
$merge = explode(',', $merge); //Merge SKUs
$mpages = explode(',', $mpages); //Merge Pages
$mcallouts = explode(',', $mcallouts); //Merge Callouts
$mcallout_nid = explode(',', $mcallout_nid);  //Merge Current callout
if($merge[0] !== '0') {
    //Store NIDs of Old Callouts to the proper SKU
    $oc_sku = array();
    $oc_sku_e = count($merge);
    $oc_sku_ee = 0;
    while ($oc_sku_ee < $oc_sku_e) {
        $curr_sku = $merge[$oc_sku_ee];
        $curr_oldco = $mcallout_nid[$oc_sku_ee];
        $oc_sku[$curr_sku] = $curr_oldco;
        $oc_sku_ee++;
    }

    //Convert page numbers to page_nids
    $pc = count($mpages); //How many pages are we getting
    $pc_e = 0;
    while($pc_e < $pc) {
        $nid = $mpages[$pc_e];
        $sql = db_query('SELECT * FROM content_type_page WHERE field_page_order_value = "%d" AND field_project_nid = "%d" ORDER BY vid DESC LIMIT 1', $nid, $project_nid);
        $res = db_fetch_array($sql);
        if($res) {
            $npage_arr[] = $res['nid'];
        } else {  //If there is no page, we need to create it here.
            $node = new StdClass();
            $node->type = 'page';
            $node->title = 'Page ' . $nid . ' of ' . $project->title;
            $node->field_project[0]['nid'] = $project_nid;
            $node->field_page_order[0]['value'] = $nid;
            $node = node_submit($node);
            node_save($node);
            $npage_arr[] = $node->nid;
        }
    $pc_e++;
    }


    // Convert callout letters to callout_nids
    $coc = count($mcallouts);
    $coc_e = 0;
    while($coc_e < $coc) {
        $cnid = strtoupper($mcallouts[$coc_e]);
        $pnid = $npage_arr[$coc_e];
        $page_node = node_load($pnid);
        $sql = db_query('SELECT * FROM content_type_callout WHERE field_identifier_value = "%s" AND field_page_nid = "%d" ORDER BY vid DESC LIMIT 1', $cnid, $pnid);
        $res = db_fetch_array($sql);
        if($res) {
            $cpage_arr[] = $res['nid'];
        } else { //If there is no callout that exists, we need to make it here.
            $callout_node = new stdClass();
            $callout_node->type = 'callout';
            $callout_node->field_page[0]['nid'] = $pnid;
            $callout_node->field_identifier[0]['value'] = $cnid;
            $callout_node->field_sequence[0]['value'] = 0;
            $callout_node->title = "Callout ".$callout." on page ".$page_node->field_page_order[0]['value'];
            $callout_node->field_project[0]['nid'] = $project->nid;
            $callout_node->field_wholesaler[0]['value'] = $project->field_wholesaler[0]['value'];
            $callout_node->field_skus = array();

            $callout_node->status = 1;
            $callout_node->uid = 1;             
            $callout_node->revision = true;
            $callout_node = node_submit($callout_node);
            node_save($callout_node);
            $cpage_arr[] = $callout_node->nid;
        }
    $coc_e++;
    }

    //Now we need to assign the skus to the appropriate callout for processing
    $coc2 = count($cpage_arr);
    $coc_e2 = 0;
    while($coc_e2 < $coc2) {
        $co = $cpage_arr[$coc_e2];
        if($co !== '0') {
            $sku = $merge[$coc_e2];
            $m_arr[$co][] = $sku;
        }
    $coc_e2++;
    }

    //we need a way to centrally store all NID's of SKUs to the callouts they belong to
    $oc_arr = array();
    $oc = count($mcallout_nid);
    $oc_e = 0;
    while($oc_e < $oc) {
        $f_callout = $mcallout_nid[$oc_e];
        $former_callout = node_load($f_callout);
        foreach($former_callout->field_skus as $key=>$skus) {
            $oc_arr[] = $skus;
        }
        $oc_e++;
    }

    //Now we are processing the Pages/Callouts/SKUs to save
    $pc_e2 = 0;
    foreach($m_arr as $key=>$values) {
        $callout = node_load($key);
        foreach($values as $value) {
            $oc = count($oc_arr);
            $oc_e = 0;
            while($oc_e < $oc) {
                $skus = $oc_arr[$oc_e];
                if($value == $skus['nid']) {
                    $callout->field_skus[] = $skus;
                    //$nid = $oc_sku[$value];
                    $old_callout_info[] = $oc_sku[$value];
                    $oc_e = $oc;
                }
                else {
                    $oc_e++;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach($old_callout_info as $nid) {
/*          $nid = $oc_sku[$value]; */
            $former_callout = node_load($nid);
            foreach($former_callout->field_images as $old_image) {
            $callout->field_images[] = $old_image;
            }
            foreach($former_callout->field_line_art as $old_image) {
                $callout->field_line_art[] = $old_image;
            }
            foreach($former_callout->field_swatches as $old_image) {
                $callout->field_swatches[] = $old_image;
            }
            $callout->field_copy_text[0]['value'] .= $former_callout->field_copy_text[0]['value'];
        }
        $callout->field_notes[0]['value'] .= $former_callout->field_notes[0]['value'];
        $callout->field_image_notes[0]['value'] .= $former_callout->field_image_notes[0]['value'];
        $callout->field_logos = $former_callout->field_logos;
        $callout->field_affiliations = $former_callout->field_affiliations;
        $callout->field_graphics = $former_callout->field_graphics;
        $callout->revision = 1;



        $callout->field_status[0]['value'] = 'inprocess';
        node_save($callout);
        $pc_e2++;
    }
    }
```

I realize this can probably be simplified in a way, but as for now, this works perfectly considering what I'm trying to do.  No complaints from the client so far.  Thanks for taking a look Drupal Community.